# How to export a raster into ascii without nodata values?

Tags: raster, export

I need to export a grd raster file into ascii .xyz without nodata values. This is not a problem in itself...I´m using Saga-GIS export grid to xyz module.(ArcGIS 10.01 produces a very strange table of xyz values with lots of fields??)...but the person who wants to use the data would like it without the no-data values. The project area is a state border - so there are always going to be no-data values within the bounding box due to the unregular nature of the border.

The data will be used in WINDPRO (which I do not have so I can´t test it).

1. is there a way to export a raster without getting no-data values?
2. Does anyone know windpro, and what could the problem be with no-data values?

thanks for any suggestions,

rob

Comment: The no-data values were given the value -999 and not actually "no-data" as text. Maybe this is the problem? How would I define the -999 as no-data? Can I do this in SAGA-GIS?

Answer (score 2):

You can use gdal_translate's -a_nodata flag to give your no data's a value.  You're right though, I would think that you would be better off leaving the no data's as no data.

Here's a manual for gdal_translate:

[gdal_translate manual](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html)

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
sed '/-999$/d' infile.xyz > outfile.xyz
```

Awk and Perl would also be possibilities.